# What are the definition of an algebra and $\sigma$-algebra and the proof of this theorem?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, terminology

> Suppose that $\Omega$ is an infinite set (countable or not), and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the family of all subsets which are either finite or have a finite complement. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra, but not a $\sigma$-algebra.

I have trouble understand the definition of sigma algebra and algebra. The theorem tells me to distinguish between them. I have no idea how to prove that theorem. Please justify the definition of these two algebra and at least give some hint for me to proof these theorem.

Comment: An algebra only allows **finite** operations such as unions and intersections and complements, a $\sigma$-algebra allows **countable** applications of these operations. Since that's the key difference you want to show that this satisfies finite complements, and finite unions, but demonstrate that one of a countable union/intersection/complement will fail.

Comment: I have no experience of writing formal proof, i am wondering how do you do this?@AdamHughes

Comment: @Victor, if you have no experience writing formal proofs, trying to prove results in measure theory is quite a leap. Perhaps you could get experience working with formal proofs with something like math analysis (which would be using $\varepsilon-\delta$ arguments), before jumping into measure theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's have a look at how such a proof needs to go. First we need to see that this **is** an algebra, so let's see

- Clearly both $\varnothing,\Omega\in\mathcal{A}$ since $\Omega$ is infinite.
- If $A\in\mathcal{A}$ then either $|A|=\infty$ or $|A^c|=\infty$, either way $A^c\in\mathcal{A}$
- If $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$ there are four possibilities

$$\begin{cases} |A|<\infty, |B|<\infty \\ |A|<\infty, |B^c|<\infty \\ |A^c|<\infty, |B|<\infty \\ |A^c|<\infty, |B^c|<\infty\end{cases}$$

We see if so then we conclude

$$\begin{cases} |A\cup B|\le |A|+|B|<\infty \\ |(A\cup B)^c|<|B^c|<\infty \\ |(A\cup B)^c|<|A^c|<\infty \\ |(A\cup B)^c|<|A^c|<\infty\end{cases}$$

so we have an algebra by the definitions.

Now if we demonstrate that for some collection of $\{A_n\}\subseteq\in\mathcal{A}$ we have

$$\left|\bigcup_n A_n\right|=\left|\bigcap_n A_n^c\right|=\infty$$

then we see this is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Can you see some simple sets in $A$ which could work? Hint:  try some small finite sets.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a set. A nonempty collection $\mathscr A$ of subsets of $S$ is an *algebra* if it is closed under the simple operations of union, intersection, and complement (in $S$). That is, if $A\in\mathscr A$ and $B\in\mathscr A$, then $$A\cup B\in \mathscr A,$$ $$A\cap B\in \mathscr A,$$ and $$S\setminus A\in\mathscr A.$$

If it is also true that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\in\mathscr A$$ whenever each $A_i\in\mathscr A$, then $\mathscr A$ is also a *sigma algebra* (often written as "$\sigma$-algebra"). The symbol "$\sigma$" is frequently used to denote some sort of countable additive-like aspect of a property or operation.

**Comment:** Note that it follows from this definition that $\varnothing$ and $S$ are both always in $\mathscr A$. Just choose any element, so its complement is also an element, and thus the intersection of the element and its complement (which is $\varnothing$) is an element, and then the complement of that (which is $S$) is an element. One can also easily show that countably infinite intersections of elements are again elements, using complements.